# How to get current subdomain in Next.js 13.4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

In Next.js version 13.4.13 using the pages router. I want to get the subdomain from the current URL on the server, so I used the `getServerSideProps` function which looks like this

```
tsx
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    const domainCookie: CookieValueTypes = getCookie(Cookies.DOMAIN_INFO, { req, res });

    let domain: IDomain | null = null;

    if (!domainCookie) {
        if (!req || !req.headers || !req.headers.host) throw new Error("Can't get current subdomain");

        const subdomain = req.headers.host.split(':')[0];

        try {
            domain = await queryClient.fetchQuery([Endpoints.SITE, { subdomain }], domainFetching);
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.error('Unable to fetch subdomain info');
        }

        setCookie(Cookies.DOMAIN_INFO, JSON.stringify(domain), { req, res });
    } else {
        domain = JSON.parse(domainCookie as string);
    }

    // Rest of the code
};
```

The problem here is in the line where I define the `subdomain`, if I go to `http://development:3000` I want the `subdomain` to be equal to `development`, instead it equals `127.0.0.1`

Note that I have properly configured the `host` file on my machine which is responsible for domains mapping.